# How to access Course content and other canvas API data in LTI 1.3

Tags: canvas, canvas-lms, lti, ims

I have created and set up LTI 1.3 tool with LTI Key by following the canvas document - https://community.canvaslms.com/docs/DOC-16794-canvas-release-lti-13-and-lti-advantage-2019-06-22

I can launch the tool inside the canvas, and able to do the auth process and got the 'id_token' as response and canvas display my success page.

Now I need to access ( https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/courses.html#method.courses.show )
course content by canvas API, I can't access it using LTI key.

What's the solution for this?
How can I access the content data or canvas API in LTI 1.3 tool using LTI Key?

Answer (score 1):

You can not access the canvas rest API using your LTI credentials.  Event though they both use OAuth2 flows, they use different authentication scopes, keys, and flows.

If you want to access the canvas rest API, you will need to store a 'Canvas Developer Key' in addition to the LTI keyset.

Comment: Hi pfranza , Is there any official statement on this because I also think it is not possible to access REST API from LTI 1.3? Since, I need to document this to my boss and my clients any official statements would be great for me Unfortunately, I did not get any answers from community.